# My Gaming open id is not being associated with my other stackexchange accounts, is this expected?

Tags: support, user-accounts, openid

For some reason, my gaming open id is not being picked up with stackexchange and associated with my other accounts.

Is this because the site is special or something or is this a bug? Or did I do something wrong?

Comment: Keep in mind that copying profile information _doesn't_ change your alternate OpenID login.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try clicking "clear all associations" then "reassociate" on this page

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/1302/joseph?tab=accounts

That generally works so long as all accounts have at least one form of identity in common between them.

Answer (score 0):

[Your account](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/1302/joseph?tab=accounts) appears to be associated with your Server Fault and Game Dev accounts. Perhaps you were looking at your [meta profile](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1302/joseph)? It's always been the case for me that [my main gaming profile](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/3107/shaun?tab=accounts) showed my related accounts, but [my meta account](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3107/shaun) did not.

Comment: yeah I noticed those, but I have a lot of other accounts besides those, which I thought was really odd: http://stackexchange.com/users/bb5c8523-40ba-47b9-b711-3114cd161030?tab=accounts